# How to access inner polymer elements from outer polymer element

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, polymer

I want to define a new element `<my-table>` with can contain a number of
columns `<mytable-col>`
The usage should look like this:

```html
<my-table id="mt1">
 <mytable-col id="c1" title ="name" type="string"width="150"></mytable-col>
 <mytable-col id="c2" title ="age" type="number" width="60"></mytable-col>
</my-table>
```

Is it possible to define an element with another (required) new "inner"
element?
How is it possible to access from the dart code of the outer the markup of
the inner elements instances.

If both the template of `<my-table>` and `<mytable-col>` contain markup, where
is the markup of the inner `<mytable-col>` inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote your markup the `<mytable-col>` elements are children of `<my-table>` which are added to the `<content>` node inside your `<my-table>` element.

You can access those child elements from the code of your `<mytable-col>` like

```dart
var listContent = ($['content'] as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes();
```

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Is it possible to define an element with another (required) new "inner" element?

You can add code in your `enteredView()` method (after the `super.enteredView();` call that verifies that the right child nodes are available in the `<content>` node and throws an exception if not.

> where is the markup of the inner  inserted?

The markup is inserted into it's elements `shadowDOM`.
The markup changes the appearance of your element but is normally not visible,
for example when your open `view source` from your browser (except when you enable the option to show `shadowDOM` in Chromium/Dartium or your browser doesn't support `shadowDOM` then you see how polyfills try to emulate `shadowDOM`).

You can compare it with tags like `<video>` where just adding this tag creates many elements (like play-, stop-, continue-, fast-forward- buttons and `<span>`s and `<div>`s for the layout that are added behind the scenes which are responsible for the layout and behavior of the `<video>` tag but are not visible in the markup.

Comment: to the question: "Is it possible ... element?", I just wanted to know, if that approach works. As you ansered, it works, tnx.

Comment: to the question: "where is the markup of the inner inserted?": If template of <my-table> contains <p>MyTable</p> and <mytable-col> contains <p>MyCol</p>, in whitch order the output appears - inner or outer first?

Comment: The markup of the **inner** is inserted into the `<content>`tag of the **outer**. At first comes the markup of the **outer** element that is before it's `<content>` tag then comes the markup of your **innter** element and at last the makup of the **outer** element that comes after it's `<content>` tag.

Comment: Is it correct, that the content of the outer is inserted also to <content> of the outer? I don´t understand how I can influence the order (or if I cant´t, what is the order)

Comment: Seems a type: the content of the **outer** is inserted also to - should be *inner* I guess.  
Have you already seen the edit/extension to my previous comment?

Comment: your video example: I assume, the <video> corresponds to the outer and contains the video itself in it´s template. The inner element <video-contol> contains the buttons in it´s template. How can I decicde, if the video-controls appears over the video content or vice verca. The usage is <video><video-control></video-control><video> in the main html-file.

Comment: By the placement of the `<content>` tag inside the `<video>` tag's `<template>` tag. You also can have more than one `<content>` tag and define which child elements should be placed in which `<content>` tags like `<content select="mytable-col.first">` where 'mytable-col.first' is a CSS selector.

Comment: Tnx, I´ll try and ask a new question if I still have problems

Comment: I tried "var listContent = ($['content'] as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes();" but got the exception: "Uncaught Error: The null object does not have a method 'getDistributedNodes'."  because the map $ is empty. In the html I have an inner element : <click-counter id="cc1" count="5">
      Before-<span id="eins" attr attr2="xx">inner</span>-after
      </click-counter>

Comment: Then `$['content']` doesn't return an element. Check this first. Do you have the `<content></content> tag in your element's HTML?

Comment: $['content'] returns null, <content></content> is the first element in the component´s <template> (The content is displayed in the browser)

Comment: In which method is your code? Try in `enteredView()` after `super.enteredView();`

Comment: The code is in a method of the componet which is called from outside as result of a buttonclick. 
I tried in enteredView, $ ist still empty, The line "var listContent = ($['content'] as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes();" does not throw an exceptin but code after that line is not executed.

Comment: This is a bug, the exception is silently swallowed in `enteredView()`. `buttonClick` is ok - no need to put it in `enteredView()`. We should switch to chat, but the `switch to chat` button is not shown anymore.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45491/discussion-between-gunter-zochbauer-and-mica)

Answer (score 0):

with @Günter Zöchbauer ´s help I found the solution:

As he wrote you can get the inner HTML with:

```
var listContent = ($['content'] as ContentElement).getDistributedNodes();
```

Because this only finds Nodes with an id, you have do define the  Element in the Component´s HTML with an id too.

```
<content id = content><span>inner HTML</span></content>
```